# Get which item was clicked

Tags: java, android

i have little problem how i will recognize which item was clicked with OnClickEvent. I draw gridview menu with Images + Text. Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    GridView menu;
    private String[] menu_text = {
    "Menu1",
    "Menu2",
    "Menu3",
    "Menu4",
    "Menu5",
    "Menu6",
    "Menu7",
    "Menu8"};

    private Integer[] menu_icon = {
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);    

        menu = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.Menu);
        menu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        menu.setAdapter(new MenuItem(this, R.layout.menu_item, menu_text));

        }

    public class MenuItem extends ArrayAdapter {
        public MenuItem(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
            TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(menu_text[position]);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, menu_icon[position], 0, 0);
            return row;
            }

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Action to perform


    }
    }
```

So my question is how i can recognize which item was clicked in this grid menu.

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
   String menuText = menu_text[arg2];
      Drawable d  = getResources().getDrawable(menu_icon[arg2]);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arg2` int in the `onItemClick` parameters is the position of the pressed item in the array.

So

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Action to perform
    String selectedObject = objects[arg2]; //objects is the String array passed to the adapter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the OnItemClickListener documentation, you'll find out that in the onItemClick method gives you a few parameters:

> parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
>   view   The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
>   position   The position of the view in the adapter.
>   id     The row id of the item that was clicked.

position will give you the index of the clicked item

Answer (score -1):

You have overrided onItemClick method in this click, look View arg1 its The View being clicked, and 3rd paramter arg2 is position of item in gridview.